# How to fetch a value as default value in mat-select in Angular when coming from other component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular11

I have a component with a mat-select, once I choose the option and click the button next the selected value travel to the other component perfectly, but If I want to go back to change my selection, then I would like this time to have in the mat-select the old value as default value.

Using a Sharing Data Service I still have the value available but I still can not manage to inserted in the mat-select as default value.

```
export class Themas {
    themaId?: string;
    name?: string;
    autorId?: number; 
}


export class ThemanComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor(private readonly translate: TranslateService,          
          private readonly sharingDataService: SharingDataService,
          private readonly router: Router) {
     } 

     selectedThema: Themas;

     ngOnInit(): void {
         this.onBackLoadSelectedThema();
     }

     onBackLoadSelectedThema(): void{
         console.log('load thema onback' + 
                      this.sharingDataService.data.name);
     if (this.sharingDataService.data){
         this.selectedThema.name= this.sharingDataService.data.name;
     }
  }

}



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <form class="form-group">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>{{'choose.thema' | translate}}</mat-label>
                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedThema" name="thema" required >
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let thema of settings.themas" [value]="thema">{{thema.name}}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
           </mat-form-field>
        </form>
  </div>


export class MeetingComponent implements OnInit {
    themas = new Themas();
    id: string;
    constructor(private readonly translate: TranslateService,
            private readonly sharingDataService: SharingDataService,
            private readonly router: Router,
            private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
     }
     ngOnInit(): void {
         this.themas = this.sharingDataService.data;
     }
}



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
        <h2>{{'title' | translate}}<span>{{' ' + themas.name}}</span></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcKoW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`selectedThema` is an object, and you are also using the object as a value in the dropdown. Objects are compared by reference, so you need to actually create a reference to the object in your array, not just specify the name. You could use `compareWith` and not create the reference, but here I would just search for the object that has the same name:

```
if (this.sharingDataService.data) {
   this.selectedThema = 
     this.settings.themas.find(thema => thema.name === this.sharingDataService.data.name)
}
```

Comment: When I do that somehow the result is undefined, I'm calling the method onBackLoadSelectedThema() after the Request, in that way this.settings will be loaded. Here the console messages:  load thema onback: Advisoring 
SelectedThema: undefined